# Mutable class as a child of an immutable class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, immutability, mutable

I want to have immutable Java objects like this (strongly simplified):

```
class Immutable {

    protected String name;

    public Immutable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

In some cases the object should not only be readable but mutable, so I could add mutability through inheritance:

```
public class Mutable extends Immutable {

    public Mutable(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        super.name = name;
    }

}
```

While this is technically fine, I wonder if it conforms with OOP and inheritance that mutable is also of type immutable. I want to avoid the OOP crime to throw `UnsupportedOperationException` for immutable object, like the Java collections API does.

What do you think? Any other ideas?

Comment: This is exactly what Objective C does: `NSMutableString` inherits from `NSString`, `NSMutableArray` inherits from `NSArray`, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Avoid calling the parent "Immutable" because it becomes a lie in the child class - if you *do* want to make a class immutable, it should be final too in order to prevent exactly this problem.

Joda Time uses "ReadableXXX" to give the idea that "this class only provides read access; other subclasses may be mutable". I'm not sure whether I like that idea, but I can't say I've seen many alternatives.

Basically the problem is with expressing a negative - `Immutable` describes what you *can't* do (mutate it) and that can't be sensibly enforced in subclasses. (Even if the fields within `Immutable` were final, it wouldn't stop a subclass having its own mutable fields.)

Answer (score 5):

Your subclass is bad because it violates the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Don't do it.

Comment: No it doesn't. Instances of `Immutable` can be replaced by instances of `Mutable` without altering the behavior of the code.

Comment: I dont understand why this wrong answer is still here, without any edit.

Comment: code that requires immutable object would need to be updated to make defensive copies. otherwise bad things could happen in certain situations. perhaps that's not technically LSP.

Comment: The answer is correct. From the wikipedia page, "Under the definitions of Meyer and America, a MutablePoint would be a behavioral subtype of ImmutablePoint, whereas LSP forbids this." See this for a better explanation: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238176/why-would-square-inheriting-from-rectangle-be-problematic-if-we-override-the-set

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that you should have an inheritable base "ReadableFoo" class, a derived sealed ImmutableFoo class, and other derived MutableFoo classes.  Code which doesn't care whether a Foo is mutable or not can accept a ReadableFoo.  Code that wants a Foo that is guaranteed not to change can accept an ImmutableFoo.  Code which can need to change a Foo can accept a MutableFoo.

Note that the constructors for both ImmutableFoo and MutableFoo should typically accept a ReadableFoo.  That way, any Foo will be convertible to a mutable or immutable version.

Answer (score 3):

Immutable classes should be `final` precisely to avoid mutable sub-types.

Allowing a sub-type of an immutable class to break the immutable contract makes it rather pointless to have the class be immutable in the first place. It may be legal in the sense that Java allows you to do it (immutability is not enforced in the language) but such a class isn't *truly* immutable as long as it can be sub-classed.

This is why String is final.

Comment: Consider you need ImmutableCollection base class and ImmutableList, ImmutableSet subclasses. How can you make here base class final?

The thing is that no compiler can express all contraints that may appear in your model. Thus we should expect that compiler will check everything for us.

Answer (score 1):

I find your code rather curious.

To implement such an Immutable behaviour, I would rather has relied upon an `Immutable` interface, providing only the getter method, whiile the object contains both. This way, operations relying on the immutable objects would have called the interface, while others would have called the object.

And, if you really don't want your immutable objects to be casted as mutable ones, you can then use proxies, and all the enterprise tools (aspects, and so on). But usually, relying upon other developpers' goodwill is a sweet way to make them responsible of their mistakes (like casting the immutable in mutable).

Comment: Proxies can be sued to make an object read-only, but they do not make an object immutable.  The only way to make a possibly-mutable object immutable is to detach every part of it that might be mutable, in which case the object isn't much of a proxy anymore.