# Prevent/Restrict Method Inheritance

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have an application in which a number of objects are all extending an abstract class which defines methods like `create()` `edit()` `retrieve()` and `delete()`.  Since each of the child classes use the same logic for these functions, the abstract class defines that default behaviour, and in the few cases where it needs to be augmented, the child classes can override or use the hooks I've built in.

Now I'm having the situation where some of the child classes need to be made immutable, meaning that they shouldn't have `edit()` or `delete()` methods.  This need sounds to me like a job for an interface named something like `immutable` which the immutable classes could implement.  Problem is that interfaces don't stop methods from being called, they just enforce a method's existence.  So this is obviously not going to work.

Making two parent classes, one for mutable objects and one for immutable ones is ugly and is probably asking for problems down the line which maintenance.  I could have the immutable objects override the offending methods with an empty method that did nothing, but that also seems messy and like I'm not doing proper OOP at that point.

So what would you suggest as the best way to allow a large set of classes to all inherit a set of methods, but for some of them to not inherit all of the methods?  (The application in question is written php, but general OOP techniques from any language can still be helpful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create an immutable-base class as a child of the base class.
the immutable-base should implement [final](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) overrides of edit() and delete() which do nothing or throw an error.

Final, so that all immutable children are guaranteed not to be able to edit or delete

bonuses of this strategy

- easily check if an object is immutable by testing for instanceof immutable-base
- easily change objects from immutable and back again by modifing what it extends

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the hierarchy would look something like this:  Base->Immutable_Base->Immutable_Children  and  Base->Mutable_Children ?  At that point would I be better making a Mutable_Base class to place in between the Base and Mutable_Children classes?

Comment: IMHO Mutable_Base is unnecessary since Mutable is the base case.  however it's up to you and your sense of aesthetics.  Some people strongly prefer symmetry in their class trees.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. If someone calls x.delete(y), s/he expects y to be deleted from x (e.g., a Collection), and not that nothing happens. To me, the problem is already in the base class, which should be changed. Maybe a change in name only suffices, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493891/mutable-class-as-a-child-of-an-immutable-class

Answer (score 2):

Actually creating classes that have empty methods or throw errors is bad - such methods are confusing, they take up space and do nothing.

A better approach would be to make the immutable class the base class and make the mutable class extend it with adding methods for modification. This way each class has only those methods, that really belong there.

Answer (score 0):

I like Java's approach to this.  Throw an exception.  Create an `UnsupportedOperationException` and for those implementations that shouldn't use a specific method throw one to let the user know they can't use this functionality for this implementation.

Comment: I'd still have to override the `edit()` and `delete()` methods to throw the exception though, right?  And I'd have to do that in every immutable class, which doesn't seem very DRY at all.  Though throwing an exception does seem more useful than just overriding with an empty method I must say.

Comment: You would have to override the method but I'm not sure that a one line exception throw is really violating any DRY principles.  If you just want to cut down on the number of times you override you can simply create an abstract class that throws the appropriate exceptions and your immutable objects simply extend it.

Answer (score 0):

Another thought I wanted to throw out as a possible solution.  Classes could implement an interface that looks like the following:

```
Interface Immutable {
    const immutable = true;
}
```

and then the Base abstract class can write the `delete()` and `edit()` methods with

```
if (!$this->immutable) {
    //do_stuff
}
```

This would also extend well to other classifications of class, like NonDeletable and NonEditable to allow for more fine grained behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Here is super short workaround, make your method final and start it with:

```
    if(self::class!=static::class) return;#or throw an error
```

It will not prevent inheritance itself, but methods will not work in children classes (with error or without - is up to you).

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.4, you can use [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

For example, you could make a base class that only includes the methods that all child classes have:

```
class EntityManager {
    public function create() {/*...*/}
    public function retrieve() {/*...*/}
}
```

Then you could define a couple of traits:

```
trait EditTrait {
    public function edit() {/*...*/}
}

trait DeleteTrait {
    public function delete() {/*...*/}
}
```

You would then create an immutable child class like this:

```
class LogManager extends EntityManager {
    ...
}
```

And a mutable child class like this:

```
class ContactManager extends EntityManager {
    use EditTrait;
    use DeleteTrait;

    ...
}
```

Traits have some advantages over some of the other solutions here such as:

- No duplication of code.
- Single base class.
- Methods that don't work or don't make sense, don't appear on classes that don't support them (especially important for docs and apis).