# PHP - Return specific methods from the same class

Tags: php

I am creating specific classes within my project, and I would like to know how I can return some methods within the same class.

I know that I could create a new class in a new file to return new methods based on the class that called it, however I would need to pass a lot of data to that new class. Is there any way to return the same class but limiting some methods?

```php
<?php

class Service
{
    private $data;

    private $fileName;

    public static function init()
    {
        return new Service();
    }

    public function postData($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        // return new Service(); (can be getData() or checkData())
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function checkData()
    {
        // Do some stuff

        // return new Service(); (only getData())
    }
}
```

This can happen:

```php
Service::init()->postData($data)->checkData();

Service::init()->postData($data)->checkData()->getData();

Service::init()->postData($data)->getData();
```

This can't happen:

```php
Service::init()->postData($data)->checkData()->checkData()->getData();

Service::init()->postData($data)->checkData()->postData()->getData();
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the best way, but you could store some form of object state, then when you call a method check if the state allows this call.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830623/prevent-restrict-method-inheritance) might be of use.

Comment: I would suggest interfaces...